# Time Complexity to Sort a K Sorted Array Using Quicksort Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, quicksort

**Problem:**

I have to analyze the time complexity to sort (*using Quick sort*) a list of integer values which are almost sorted.

**What I have done?**

I have read [SO Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55615707/sorting-nearly-sorted-array-with-onlogk-complexity),  [SO Q2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53734024/why-quicksort-bad-at-sorting-almost-sorted-data), [SO Q3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35884216/why-insertion-sort-is-best-algorithm-for-sorted-or-nearly-sorted-array#35884315) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11963986/quick-sort-time-complexity).

However, I have not found anything which mentioned explicitly the time complexity to sort a k sorted array using Quick sort.

Since the time complexity of Quick sort algorithm depends on the strategy of choosing pivot and there is a probability to face the worst case due to having almost sorted data, to avoid worst case, I have used median of three values(*first, middle, last*) as a pivot as referred [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4019528/quick-sort-worst-case#4019832).

**What do I think?**

Since in average case, the time complexity of Quick sort algorithm is `O(n log(n))` and as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35884216/why-insertion-sort-is-best-algorithm-for-sorted-or-nearly-sorted-array#35884315), "For any non trivial value of n, a divide and conquer algorithm will need many O(n) passes, even if the array be almost completely sorted",

I think the time complexity to sort a k sorted array using Quick sort algorithm is `O(n log(n))`, if the worst case does not occur.

**My Question:**

Am I right that the time complexity to sort a k sorted array using Quick sort algorithm is `O(n log(n))` if I try to avoid worst case selecting a proper pivot and if the worst case does not occur.

Answer (score 1):

When you say time complexity of Quick Sort, it is `O(n^2)`, because the worst case is assumed by default. However, if you use another strategy to choose pivot, like Randomized Quick Sort, for example, your time complexity is still going to be O(n^2) by default. But the expected time complexity is `O(n log(n))`, since the occurrence of the worst case is highly unlikely. So if you can prove somehow that the worst case is 100% guaranteed not to happen, then you can say time complexity is less than `O(n^2)`, otherwise, by default, the worst case is considered, no matter how unlikely.

Comment: Although run time will be slower by a constant factor, using [median of medians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians) guarantees O(n log(n)) time complexity. However this is somewhat of a hybrid sort, since insertion sort is typically used to sort groups of 5 elements.

Comment: @ rcgldr  Thanks for your valuable information "median of medians".